# Unable to get apt-update and apt-upgrade to work on Bliss OS using Termux

Tags: termux, virtualbox

Ideally, I am trying to gain root access to a Bliss OS (version 11.14) Virtualbox machine I have so that I can view saved PCAP files. Sadly, to get to the directory I have to be root. The only option seems to be installing a fake root module (https://www.crisisshelter.org/get-root-access-in-termux-without-root-fakeroot/).

However, this and several other things I have tried to do with Termux lead up to running `apt-update` and `apt-upgrade`. However, I keep seeming to get repository issues.

```
$ apt update && apt upgrade
Get:1 https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease [16.8 kB]
Get:2 https://grimler.se/game-packages-24 games InRelease [9347 B]
Err:1 https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO PUBKEY B0076E4908716168
Get:3 https://grimler.se/science-packages-24 science InRelease [9360 B]
Err:2 https://grimler.se/game-packages-24 games InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BO076E4908716168
Err:3 https://grimler.se/science-packages-24 science InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B0076E490871616B
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO PUBKEY B0076E490871616B
E: The repository 'https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now. N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
W: GPG error: https://grimler.se/game-packages-24 games InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B0076E490B71616B
E: The repository 'https://grimler.se/game-packages-24 games InRelease' is not signed. N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
W: GPG error: https://grimler.se/science-packages-24 science InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO PUBKEY B0076E490B71616B
E: The repository 'https://grimler.se/science-packages-24 science InRelease' is not signed.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
```

<sup>[Screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIpft.png)</sup>

I can't seem to find a fix for Termux anywhere online. Does anyone have a better solution to getting root access via Termux?

UPDATE: I updated termux to a more modern version. However, I get "File has unexpected size" error when I try to run `apt-get` update, or when I try to install anything.

```
~ $ pkg install su
Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Get:1 https://packages. termux.dev/apt/termux-main stable InRelease [14.0 kB]
Get:2 https://packages. termux.dev/apt/termux-main stable/main x86_64 Packages [450 kB]
Ign:2 https://packages. termux.dev/apt/termux-main stable/main x86_64 Packages
Err:2 https://packages. termux.org/apt/termux-main stable/main x86_64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (451382 != 450311). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 216.18.208.174 443]
Err:2 https://packages. termux.org/apt/termux-main stable/main x86_64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (451382 != 450311). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 216.18.208.174 443]
Err:2 https://packages. termux.org/apt/termux-main stable/main x86_64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (451382 != 450311). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 216.18.208.174 443]
Fetched 14.0 kB in 1s (10.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://packages. termux.org/apt/termux-main/dists/stable/main/binary-x86_64/Packages File has unexpected size (451382 != 450311). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 216.18.208.174 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

<sup>[Screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TryEy.png)</sup>

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: *I am trying to gain root access ... so that I can view saved PCAP files* -- why do you need root access for this? Where (exact location) are these PCAP files saved? Are you unable to copy them to /sdcard (aka Internal Storage)?

Comment: You have added a repository but not it's PGP key. Use `apt-key add <site-public-key.gpg>` e.g. on the [published key here](https://grimler.se/pubkey/).

Comment: @Firelord I am attempting to view pcap information generated via csploit for a senior project im doing. It seems the only location the pcap files are saved are: /data/user/0/org.csploit.android/cache/csploit-sniff-*randomnumber*.pcap. The So far, I have not found a way to changed the save location in csploit, and I get a permission denied error when i try to access that exact directory.

Comment: @Robert is site-public-key.gpg something i should already have on my system? Or is that something I have to find somewhere? Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: If you add a repository you also have to add the matching PGP key. I have posted the link to the page where the key is linked on in my last comment.

Comment: @Robert I have not added any new repositories (i think?). All I've done was change from the default termux repository "the official repositories" (I was getting errors from there as well) to the "Mirrors by grimler repository. Every time i try to install anything with apt or pkg, I get the same errors.

Comment: Do you use Termux from Play Store or F-Droid? The PlayStore version is outdated and will not be updated. May be this is the reason, or your installation is pretty old. Repository keys some times change then you also have to manually add them as I described (if you trust the key and the repo).

Comment: @Robert I downloaded this termux version from the Aurora Store.

Comment: Aurora uses GooglePlay Store as APK source so you should have the outdated version.

Comment: @Robert, Where could I find a more updated version, or do you have a suggestion on a better terminal i can use? I mean the other one i have is the Terminal Emulator app, but that too is giving me permission denied when i try to access /data/user/0, nor does it seem recognize any basic utilities like termux does (such as apt, pkg, etc...).

Comment: I asked you if you use the version from Google Play or F-Droid... I would consider this as a broad hint. Alternatively please google `termux download`.

Comment: Robert I had the Google Play version. I have updated to what i think is the most recent (0.118.0), however when i run apt-get update i now get the error: "File has unexpected size (451382 != 540311). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 216.18.208.174 443]

Comment: Just a tip, please copy and paste the text output from the terminal instead of posting a screenshot since images are not really accessible to some.

Answer (score 0):

Your link about the fakeroot module seems to be one of these websites that are created by bots to get money using website ads.

PCAP file is just network traffic capture as a file.

If you are just interested in the network traffic being captured regardless of the file or the format, I recommend you to use [HttpCanary](https://apkpure.com/httpcanary-%E2%80%94-http-sniffer-capture-analysis/com.guoshi.httpcanary).